# Trying to find a String inside a sequence of Strings with XPath

Tags: xpath, pmd

I ran into an error that states "XPath failed due to: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains()('string1', 'string2')" when I'm trying to use contain to find one string inside a sequence.

My code is related to resolving my other question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006479/with-pmd-and-xpath-can-i-determine-if-two-node-sets-have-any-node-in-common

```
Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix
[
contains(ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/FieldDeclaration/VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId/@Image,./Name/@Image)
]
```

I ran into this issue because VariableDeclaratorId/@Image returns two string when there are multiple fields to parse. I haven't found solution to resolve this. I thought about using predicates, but this contains is inside of a predicate already, doing VariableDeclaratorId/@Image[./Name/@Image] wouldn't work because this [./Name/@Image] is different from PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image.

**Expected Output:**

```
    <Expression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="30" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
        <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="30" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
            <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="30" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                <Name BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="30" EndLine="6" Image="m_foo" Label=""/>
            </PrimaryPrefix>
        </PrimaryExpression>
    </Expression>


    <Expression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="30" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
        <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="30" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
            <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="30" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                <Name BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="30" EndLine="7" Image="m_two" Label=""/>
            </PrimaryPrefix>
        </PrimaryExpression>
    </Expression>
```

**Jave Source:**

```
public class domainFunction {
    private int m_foo; // OK

    public void bar() {  
      calculate (random);
      System.out.println(m_foo);
      System.out.println(m_two);
    }
  }
```

**RAW XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <CompilationUnit BeginColumn="1" BeginLine="1" EndColumn="3" EndLine="13" Image="" Label="" declarationsAreInDefaultPackage="true">
        <TypeDeclaration BeginColumn="1" BeginLine="1" EndColumn="3" EndLine="13" Image="" Label="">
            <ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration Abstract="false" BeginColumn="8" BeginLine="1" EndColumn="3" EndLine="13" Final="false" Image="domainFunction" Interface="false" Label="" Modifiers="1" Native="false" Nested="false" PackagePrivate="false" Private="false" Protected="false" Public="true" Static="false" Strictfp="false" Synchronized="false" Transient="false" Volatile="false">
                <ClassOrInterfaceBody BeginColumn="29" BeginLine="1" EndColumn="3" EndLine="13" Image="" Label="">
                    <ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration AnonymousInnerClass="false" BeginColumn="5" BeginLine="2" EndColumn="22" EndLine="2" EnumChild="false" Image="" Label="">
                        <FieldDeclaration Abstract="false" Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="2" EndColumn="22" EndLine="2" Final="false" Image="" InterfaceMember="false" Label="" Modifiers="4" Native="false" PackagePrivate="false" Private="true" Protected="false" Public="false" Static="false" Strictfp="false" Synchronized="false" SyntacticallyFinal="false" SyntacticallyPublic="false" SyntacticallyStatic="false" Transient="false" VariableName="m_foo" Volatile="false">
                            <Type Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="2" EndColumn="15" EndLine="2" Image="" Label="" TypeImage="int">
                                <PrimitiveType Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="2" Boolean="false" EndColumn="15" EndLine="2" Image="int" Label=""/>
                            </Type>
                            <VariableDeclarator BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="2" EndColumn="21" EndLine="2" Image="" Label="">
                                <VariableDeclaratorId Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="2" EndColumn="21" EndLine="2" ExceptionBlockParameter="false" Image="m_foo" Label=""/>
                            </VariableDeclarator>
                        </FieldDeclaration>
                    </ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration>
                    <ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration AnonymousInnerClass="false" BeginColumn="5" BeginLine="3" EndColumn="22" EndLine="3" EnumChild="false" Image="" Label="">
                        <FieldDeclaration Abstract="false" Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="3" EndColumn="22" EndLine="3" Final="false" Image="" InterfaceMember="false" Label="" Modifiers="4" Native="false" PackagePrivate="false" Private="true" Protected="false" Public="false" Static="false" Strictfp="false" Synchronized="false" SyntacticallyFinal="false" SyntacticallyPublic="false" SyntacticallyStatic="false" Transient="false" VariableName="m_two" Volatile="false">
                            <Type Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="3" EndColumn="15" EndLine="3" Image="" Label="" TypeImage="int">
                                <PrimitiveType Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="13" BeginLine="3" Boolean="false" EndColumn="15" EndLine="3" Image="int" Label=""/>
                            </Type>
                            <VariableDeclarator BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="3" EndColumn="21" EndLine="3" Image="" Label="">
                                <VariableDeclaratorId Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="3" EndColumn="21" EndLine="3" ExceptionBlockParameter="false" Image="m_two" Label=""/>
                            </VariableDeclarator>
                        </FieldDeclaration>
                    </ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration>
                    <ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration AnonymousInnerClass="false" BeginColumn="5" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="5" EndLine="11" EnumChild="false" Image="" Label="">
                        <MethodDeclaration Abstract="false" BeginColumn="12" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="5" EndLine="11" Final="false" Image="" InterfaceMember="false" Label="" MethodName="bar" Modifiers="1" Native="false" PackagePrivate="false" Private="false" Protected="false" Public="true" Static="false" Strictfp="false" Synchronized="false" SyntacticallyAbstract="false" SyntacticallyPublic="true" Transient="false" Void="true" Volatile="false">
                            <ResultType BeginColumn="12" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="15" EndLine="4" Image="" Label="" Void="true" returnsArray="false"/>
                            <MethodDeclarator BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="21" EndLine="4" Image="bar" Label="" ParameterCount="0">
                                <FormalParameters BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="21" EndLine="4" Image="" Label="" ParameterCount="0"/>
                            </MethodDeclarator>
                            <Block BeginColumn="23" BeginLine="4" EndColumn="5" EndLine="11" Image="" Label="" containsComment="false">
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="22" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="">
                                    <LocalVariableDeclaration Abstract="false" Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Final="false" Image="" Label="" Modifiers="0" Native="false" PackagePrivate="true" Private="false" Protected="false" Public="false" Static="false" Strictfp="false" Synchronized="false" Transient="false" VariableName="random" Volatile="false">
                                        <Type Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="9" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="" TypeImage="int">
                                            <PrimitiveType Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="5" Boolean="false" EndColumn="9" EndLine="5" Image="int" Label=""/>
                                        </Type>
                                        <VariableDeclarator BeginColumn="11" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="">
                                            <VariableDeclaratorId Array="false" ArrayDepth="0" BeginColumn="11" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="16" EndLine="5" ExceptionBlockParameter="false" Image="random" Label=""/>
                                            <VariableInitializer BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="">
                                                <Expression BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="5" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                            <Literal BeginColumn="20" BeginLine="5" CharLiteral="false" EndColumn="21" EndLine="5" FloatLiteral="false" Image="12" IntLiteral="true" Label="" SingleCharacterStringLiteral="false" StringLiteral="false"/>
                                                        </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                    </PrimaryExpression>
                                                </Expression>
                                            </VariableInitializer>
                                        </VariableDeclarator>
                                    </LocalVariableDeclaration>
                                </BlockStatement>
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="25" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                    <Statement BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="25" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                        <StatementExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="24" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="24" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="15" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                    <Name BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="15" EndLine="6" Image="calculate" Label=""/>
                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="24" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="24" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <ArgumentList BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="23" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                            <Expression BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="23" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                                <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="23" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="">
                                                                    <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="23" EndLine="6" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                        <Name BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="6" EndColumn="23" EndLine="6" Image="random" Label=""/>
                                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                            </Expression>
                                                        </ArgumentList>
                                                    </Arguments>
                                                </PrimarySuffix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </StatementExpression>
                                    </Statement>
                                </BlockStatement>
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="24" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                    <Statement BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="24" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                        <StatementExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="23" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="23" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="15" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                    <Name BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="15" EndLine="7" Image="calculate" Label=""/>
                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="23" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="17" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="23" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <ArgumentList BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="22" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                            <Expression BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="22" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                                <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="22" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="">
                                                                    <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="22" EndLine="7" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                        <Name BeginColumn="18" BeginLine="7" EndColumn="22" EndLine="7" Image="m_foo" Label=""/>
                                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                            </Expression>
                                                        </ArgumentList>
                                                    </Arguments>
                                                </PrimarySuffix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </StatementExpression>
                                    </Statement>
                                </BlockStatement>
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="32" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                    <Statement BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="32" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                        <StatementExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="31" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="31" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="24" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                    <Name BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="24" EndLine="8" Image="System.out.println" Label=""/>
                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="25" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="31" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="25" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="31" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <ArgumentList BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="30" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                            <Expression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="30" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                                <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="30" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="">
                                                                    <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="30" EndLine="8" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                        <Name BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="8" EndColumn="30" EndLine="8" Image="m_foo" Label=""/>
                                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                            </Expression>
                                                        </ArgumentList>
                                                    </Arguments>
                                                </PrimarySuffix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </StatementExpression>
                                    </Statement>
                                </BlockStatement>
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="32" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                    <Statement BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="32" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                        <StatementExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="31" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="31" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="24" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                    <Name BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="24" EndLine="9" Image="System.out.println" Label=""/>
                                                </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="25" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="31" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="25" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="31" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <ArgumentList BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="30" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                            <Expression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="30" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                                <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="30" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="">
                                                                    <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="30" EndLine="9" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                        <Name BeginColumn="26" BeginLine="9" EndColumn="30" EndLine="9" Image="m_two" Label=""/>
                                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                            </Expression>
                                                        </ArgumentList>
                                                    </Arguments>
                                                </PrimarySuffix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </StatementExpression>
                                    </Statement>
                                </BlockStatement>
                                <BlockStatement Allocation="false" BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="28" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                    <Statement BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="28" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                        <StatementExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="27" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                            <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="27" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="7" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="10" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="this" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="true"/>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="" Arguments="false" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="11" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="20" EndLine="10" Image="calculate" Label=""/>
                                                <PrimarySuffix ArgumentCount="1" Arguments="true" ArrayDereference="false" BeginColumn="21" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="27" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                    <Arguments ArgumentCount="1" BeginColumn="21" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="27" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                        <ArgumentList BeginColumn="22" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="26" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                            <Expression BeginColumn="22" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="26" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                                <PrimaryExpression BeginColumn="22" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="26" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="">
                                                                    <PrimaryPrefix BeginColumn="22" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="26" EndLine="10" Image="" Label="" SuperModifier="false" ThisModifier="false">
                                                                        <Name BeginColumn="22" BeginLine="10" EndColumn="26" EndLine="10" Image="m_foo" Label=""/>
                                                                    </PrimaryPrefix>
                                                                </PrimaryExpression>
                                                            </Expression>
                                                        </ArgumentList>
                                                    </Arguments>
                                                </PrimarySuffix>
                                            </PrimaryExpression>
                                        </StatementExpression>
                                    </Statement>
                                </BlockStatement>
                            </Block>
                        </MethodDeclaration>
                    </ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration>
                </ClassOrInterfaceBody>
            </ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration>
        </TypeDeclaration>
    </CompilationUnit>
```

Comment: Hello, @ttback. The reason you're not getting answers (to this or your previous question) is because you are not writing questions that lend themselves to easy answers. You should always provide the input XML (which you've done) and the *exact* desired output that you're looking for based on that input. Here you've shown us an error you received and some random expressions you've tried, but you *never told us what the expected output is* and *we cannot read minds*.

Comment: @lwburk : I added the expected output if it can make it more clear. Sorry if it were not clear enough, I was a bit rushed when I post this. There was a ton of stuffs on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the contains() function because you have guessed incorrectly that it tests whether a set of strings contains a given string. Don't guess, read the spec: that's not what contains() does; rather, it tests whether one string contains another as a substring. To test whether a set of strings $S contains a string $T, use ($S = $T).

Comment: Thanks. Got it resolved. I didn't find this spec until tonight. I wasted too much time on reading and guessing on PMD's doc without looking enough into XPath. Also it wasn't clear which XPath spec PMD is using at one point. It took me a while to sort these basics out. Thanks again.